# Sorting SharedPreferences using TreeMap - Not sorting it correctly

Tags: java, android, sorting, sharedpreferences, treemap

So I need to sort an SharedPreferences, that got Float numbers in it.

So I add data with;

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(
            "Huskr_headline", 0).edit();
            editor.putFloat(tilfoejopgave_headline.getText().toString(), Float.valueOf(tilfoejopgave_klokken.getText().toString()));
            editor.commit();
```

And get the data with;

```
SharedPreferences Huskr_headline = getSharedPreferences(
            "Huskr_headline", 0);

TreeMap<String, ?> Huskr_headline_treemap = new TreeMap<String, Object>(
            Huskr_headline.getAll());

for (Map.Entry<String, ?> entry : Huskr_headline_treemap.entrySet()) {

}
```

which outputs in values;

10, 12, 14, 17, 8, 81, 9

When in turn I want it to output values;

8, 9, 10, 12, 14, 17, 81

How to make it do this? The keys are something random in String.. I guess I need to sort by value, but how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provide the `TreeMap` with a custom `Comparator` and it will use that to sort the entries in the map however you need.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

**Found the answer**

Used this
        private static Map sortByComparator(Map unsortMap) {

```
    List list = new LinkedList(unsortMap.entrySet());

    // sort list based on comparator
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator() {
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            return ((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) (o1)).getValue())
                    .compareTo(((Map.Entry) (o2)).getValue());
        }
    });

    // put sorted list into map again
    // LinkedHashMap make sure order in which keys were inserted
    Map sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap();
    for (Iterator it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) it.next();
        sortedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return sortedMap;
}
```

with this;

```
    SharedPreferences Huskr_headline_conn = getSharedPreferences(
            "Huskr_headline", 0);
    Map<String, ?> Huskr_headline = Huskr_headline_conn.getAll();


    Map<String, String> sortedMap = sortByComparator(Huskr_headline);

    for (Map.Entry entry : sortedMap.entrySet()) {
 }
```

The function found on http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-sort-a-map-in-java/